# How can I make the "purple template" for "each question"?

Tags: multicol

I found this template on tex.stackexchange page.

I don't want the page style to change and

I have 1 more requests:

1. I want to go to the other side of the page without `\\[1cm]`.
   [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[O]{\textsc{}~\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% 
\newcounter{numex}
% 
\def\thrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.5ex depth \dimexpr2pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}
% 
\newcommand\Startex{%
\stepcounter{numex}
\begin{center}
\textsc\thrulefill~{\bfseries Question~\thenumex)}~\thrulefill
\end{center}}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\Startex
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:solve}
x^2-5x+6 = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
\end{equation}
and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solve}\\[1cm]
% 
\Startex
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:solve}
x^2-5x+6 = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
\end{equation}
and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solve}\\[1cm]
% 
\Startex
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:solve}
x^2-5x+6 = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
\end{equation}
and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solve}
% 
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think, I understand your question. Are you asking about how to create the boxes using the appropriate packages or are you asking about the vertical distance between your Question-segments?

Comment: I want to create purple template for each "question" and I don't want to use ```\\[3cm]``` to pass on the other side of the page

Comment: For example, I said ```\\[3cm]```. I have ```\\[1cm]``` in my code. I mean exactly: I use the ```\\[1cm]``` to write question 5 or question 6 on the right of the page. I want to write directly from the top right without using vertical space. And I want to create purple template for each "question".

Comment: I'm beginning to understand. So essentitally what you want is the boxes as a template as a replacement for your definition of the Questions, right? Have you tried using `tcolorbox` or Alexis Flesch's `boiboites`?

Comment: Yes i want to use purple template. I didn't try them but I couldn't generate the code. By the way, I added an new image.

Comment: I understand. But i'm a bit of a rookie at this. I added a new image. Can you help me with the code to prepare a page like there sir?

Comment: @Pitaya88: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but is the following the output you would like to achieve? https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1wWR.png

Comment: I want it to be exactly like this. I also want a straight line in the middle of the page. I can probably add myself. It wouldn't be bad if there was a vertical distance between the questions.

Comment: It would also be nice if there was a horizontal distance between question 1 and question 3.

Comment: You can add a vertical line between columns using `\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}`.  See multicol manual page 3 and 8.

Comment: You can end a column using `\columnbreak` (page 5).  Why don't you look through the tcolorbox manual and see if any of the normal styles will do?

Comment: yes i have a one problem thanks @john. I will try for other problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does any of these do what you need?

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[O]{\textsc{}~\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% 
\newcounter{numex}
\newcommand\equationnumberoffset{0}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setequationnumberoffset[1]{%
  \edef\equationnumberoffset{\number\numexpr#1\relax}%
}%
\renewcommand\theequation{\@arabic{\number\numexpr\c@equation-\equationnumberoffset\relax}}%
\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\equationnumberoffset{\number\value{equation}}%
  \renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{numex}.\@arabic{\number\numexpr\c@equation-\equationnumberoffset\relax}}%
  \stepcounter{numex}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Question~\thenumex,
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-3.75mm},
  boxed title style={size=normal,colframe=blue, colback=blue!10, boxsep=0mm},
  colframe=blue, colback=white, coltitle=black, top=5.5mm]
  #1%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \endgroup
}%
\makeatother
% 
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
% 

\begin{document}
%
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveA}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveA}\par\endgroup
}

\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveB}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
   x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveB}\par\endgroup
}

\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveC}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveC}\par\endgroup
} 

\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveD}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveD}\par\endgroup
}

\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveE}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
   x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveE}\par\endgroup
}

\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveF}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveF}\par\endgroup
} 

\end{multicols*}

\noindent A \hfill B

% We have 18 equations but want to continue with equation number 7
\setequationnumberoffset{12}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

---

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[O]{\textsc{}~\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% 
\newcounter{numex}
\newcommand\equationnumberoffset{0}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setequationnumberoffset[1]{%
  \edef\equationnumberoffset{\number\numexpr#1\relax}%
}%
\renewcommand\theequation{\@arabic{\number\numexpr\c@equation-\equationnumberoffset\relax}}%
\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\equationnumberoffset{\number\value{equation}}%
  \renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{numex}.\@arabic{\number\numexpr\c@equation-\equationnumberoffset\relax}}%
  \stepcounter{numex}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Question~\thenumex,
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-3.75mm},
  boxed title style={size=normal,colframe=blue, colback=blue!10, boxsep=0mm},
  colframe=blue, colback=white, coltitle=black, top=5.5mm]
  #1%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \endgroup
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tabcolsep=.5\dimexpr1.2cm-\arrayrulewidth\relax

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X|X@{}}
\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveA}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveA}\par\endgroup
}
&
\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveB}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
   x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveB}\par\endgroup
}
\\[.5cm]
\end{tabularx}
\vskip-\lineskip
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X|X@{}}
\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveC}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveC}\par\endgroup
} 
&
\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveD}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveD}\par\endgroup
}
\\[.5cm]
\end{tabularx}
\vskip-\lineskip
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X|X@{}}
\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveE}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
   x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveE}\par\endgroup
}
&
\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveF}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveF}\par\endgroup
} 
\end{tabularx}

\noindent A \hfill B

% We have 18 equations but want to continue with equation number 7
\setequationnumberoffset{12}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I talked about that. Thank you. How do I get the vertical distance between questions?  ```\\[xcm]``` and ```\hspace{xcm}``` is not working. Also how can i start the next question from the right side of the page? Like this https://i.hizliresim.com/cp28bgx.png

Comment: Also how can I make the box edges thinner? How do I make the title box smaller? I don't want ```size=small``` (Okey I got it done with ```boxrule=0.8pt``` )

Comment: For title box smaller-- (I got it done with ```height=0.7cm``` and ```valign=center``` ).

Comment: Increasing the vertical distance with my first example is done via `\MyBox{...}\vskip{x cm}\MyBox{...}\vskip{x cm}\MyBox{...}` (or `\vfill` instead of `\vskip{x cm}` .  With my second example, which is based on `tabularx`, you find lines `\\[.5cm]`. Just choose a value larger than `.5cm`.

Comment: ```\MyBox{...}\vskip{x cm}\MyBox{...}``` and ```vskip{x cm}``` are not working but ```vspace{x cm}``` is worked. Why didn't other codes work? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Finally, When I type inside the text box, how can I prevent the next box from moving down ?

Comment: There's also this problem: the blue and red distances are not equal. https://i.hizliresim.com/5hukdpv.png  When I switch to the other side of the page using ```vspace{x cm}``` this problem happens.